# Perl - Find same sequence of characters in strings

Tags: regex, string, perl

In fact, I have a text file where sentences are written on each line  and I have to find the same sequences of characters for each sentence of each line. For instance, one of the sentences is

```
no pain no gain
```

and I want to be able to determine that the sequence of shared characters in this string is `ain`.

I tried with regular expressions (found on stackoverflow by the way) but it was to find sequences of same consecutive characters, and it's not what I'm looking for. So as a beginner in perl, I don't know how to implement that.
Thank you by advance for your time and attention.

edit: here is what I've tried but not what I want:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;

open $file, "<:encoding(utf8)", "text.txt";

while($ligne=<$file>)
{   
    while($ligne =~ /(.)\1+/g)
    {
        $gram = $1;
        print "$ligne\n";
        print "$gram\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so that other users can better help you with your solution.

Comment: I've edited a little, to break up that block of text for readability.  However, more importantly: (1) Please show the code that you have in mind but that isn't quite working. It always helps (2) Do you mean the longest sequence that repeats -- so, not `no` and of course not `in`? I suggest to offer well chosen sample input with expected results.  (And did I mention code, your code?)

Comment: In this example, why wouldn't "no" also be a match?

Comment: Or "no " which is also 3 chars long

Comment: To begin, thank you for your advices.

Comment: Then I would say that I need a trigam at least but the longest sequence that repeats would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple proof of concept that matches the `ain` of "pain" and then looks for that same match later on in the string, which it then finds in "gain". I'm using the "match named subpattern 'Match', which is how the regex matches ain (or no).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "no pain no gain";

if ($string =~ m/(?<Match>[a-zA-Z]{3}).*\k<Match>/g) {
    print "Match: $+{Match}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Match: ain
```

Note that if you change the length specifier to 2, the match becomes "no", rather than "ain".

Implementing a more robust regex for whatever your actual needs are and just iterate over every line you have and test for a match.

By the way, [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is an amazing resource for learning and practicing regular expressions. I recommend it 10000%.

Comment: But this matches specifically for length 3 --- how do you know the length of the maximal substring that repeats?  That's the problem, that we don't know that.

Comment: Thank you very mutch @Jose Fernando Lopez Fernandez, it works very well.

Comment: @zdim Indeed it matches only for length 3, but if you replace `{3}` by `{3, 6}` for example, you don't get the longest sequence but at least you get sequences between length 3 and length 6 so you can put the number of your choice.

Comment: Finally, it would be better if it could match all the sequences of length 3. For example, in this sentence: ```loud and proud and etch a sketch```, it would be matching ```oud``` and ```etc```.

Comment: @Nobunaga That (`{3,6}`) won't work -- try it.  But you _can_ scan the string repeatedly, changing that number each time. If this is normal text the number won't go too far (but once you stop you _may_ miss some).  This as it stands will always get only the first such thing in the string.  Note that in your nice example sentence above you actually have `etch` (not just `etc`)  :)